# pixelated and bad colors when using external monitor with my laptop

Tags: display-resolution, samsung, nvidia-geforce

I work with Ubuntu 21.10 (gnome 40.4.0) in a Lenovo Legion laptop with NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile]

it works really well except when I connect an external samsung monitor via HDMI. both screens have the same resolution (1920 x  1080) but while the laptop looks nice, in the external monitor fonts looks pixelated (see the clock on the top) and the colors washed out (see the word ".canvas for an example: it should be red and looks like pink with white spots)).

There is something I can do to fix it?

I took a photo with my cellphone because the screenshots looks OK.

[image: photo of the samsung monitor]

Comment: How were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same issue & unable to find a resolution.

Comment: hello, a few months later, after an automatic upgrade, the latest Ubuntu version included a Samsung generic driver for the monitor, and the problem was gone. for reference, I am running right now ubuntu 22.04, nvidia-driver-510